# JWT Token and how to use them after login?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, authentication, jwt

I like to understand the **JWT** handling of token.
I have created a login page to check if user exist in DB? If yes, I used **jwt** sign a token and return **jwt** token.

```
jwt.sign({userdata}, secretKey, (err, token) => {
                res.json({
                  token
```

After I get the token I understand I have store it in local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("token", token);
```

After this I am lost! How can I redirect the login to a protected URL once the token is stored?
Then my next question is how can I make use of the local stored token in the protected route?

For example login.html will invoke a login function call and return the token then I want to go to `/admin/admin.html`.  In `/admin/admin.html`, i have protected routes that need to use the token. How can I use it ? How can I know the user is the same user using the protected route since? I know the localstored token has the user information. Does that mean every protected route I have to post a user information and compare to local token?

Some examples of the code will be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a library that verifies your stored JWT token. You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken . This library includes a method that verifies your JWT `jwt.verify(token, secretOrPublicKey, [options, callback])`. To be able to verify a token,  you must provide the `secret key` that is used to sign your tokens. If the token is verified successfully, you can redirect the user to its designated page. As long as the token is stored and not expired, the user is remembered in the browser.

This is an approach for JS apps, however, if you're using PHP/Laravel, the token is stored in a HTTP cookie and I recommend using `jwt-auth` library, it will handle the JWT processes for you.

Comment: Yes, I did use a verify method ..
'''
jwt.verify(req.token, secretKey, (err, authData)
'''

Comment: Now it's up to you what will you do with that verified token. If it is verified successfully, you can redirect the user to the admin page, if it is not or is expired, you let the user sign in again to acquire new valid JWT token. You can decode that token, for sure it has the user ID attached to its decoded data, that ID can be used to fetch the user's data.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that

```
login() {
  try{
    const tk = response.token; // from api response
    if (tk) {
      const expiresInDuration = response.expiresIn;
      setAuthTimer(expiresInDuration);  // setTimer to not send rest call everytime if user is visiting many times
      const now = new Date();
      const expirationDate = new Date(
        now.getTime() + expiresInDuration * 1000
      );
      this.saveAuthData(this.token, expirationDate, role);
      navigate(['/home']); // function which should redirect to your desired url
    }
  }, (err) => {
      console.log(err)


 });

  }


 // function to auto logout after specified time
setAuthTimer(duration: number) {
    this.tokenTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.logout();
    }, duration * 1000);
  }

    saveAuthData(token, expirationDate, role) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('expiration', expirationDate.toISOString());
  }



// after delete and log out
 clearAuthData() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('expiration');
  }
// function to login user if its data is already present in the localStorage 
autoAuthUser() {
      authInformation = getAuthData();
    if (authInformation) {
      const now = new Date();
      const expiresIn = authInformation.expirationDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
      if (expiresIn > 0) {
        this.token = authInformation.token;
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.setAuthTimer(expiresIn / 1000);
      }
    }
  }
```

For your question regarding same user is accessing the protected route as local storage is storing token specific to user that should take care of the task